# How does this object construction with struct work internally?

Tags: ruby

Struggling to understand how an object can be created this way. What is happening behind the scenes here when constructing this object ?

```
class UserPreview < Struct.new(:gid, :email, :name)
end

u = UserPreview.new(1, 'hans@peter.de', 'Hans Peter')
=> #<struct UserPreview gid=1, email="hans@peter.de", name="Hans Peter">
```

Comment: I think the Docs provide a fairly straight forward explanation [Struct](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Struct.htm): *"A Struct is a convenient way to bundle a number of attributes together, using accessor methods, without having to write an explicit class.

The Struct class generates new subclasses that hold a set of members and their values. For each member a reader and writer method is created similar to Module#attr_accessor."*

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking. It's just a method call like any other method call. Do you understand what a method is? What a method call is? What an expression is? What a class is? It is not clear, *what precise part* you don't understand, what you do understand, what research you have done, etc.

Comment: `Struct.new` is quite special. Unlike most classes, it doesn't return an instance of its receiver (i.e. `Struct`) but an (anonymous) instance of `Class`. That's why you can inherit from its return value.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are three things to discuss in your code:

```
# 1
Struct.new(:gid, :email, :name)

# 2
class UserPreview < OtherClass
end

# 3
u = UserPreview.new(1, 'hans@peter.de', 'Hans Peter')
```

Starting with # 2:

`UserPreview` is created as a standard sub-class from `OtherClass` (in this case the result of the `Struct.new` call). We see the sub-class is not adding any new methods or attributes so it is essentially the same class as `OtherClass` with a different name. In Ruby you could simplify this as:

```
UserPreview = OtherClass
```

Because classes are just objects (of class Class).

Let's look at # 1:

What happens here is that we construct a new Struct instance with the given parameters. Under hood `Struct` is manually implemented in Ruby using C. You can look at the [code on Github](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/struct.c). I think nothing particular surprising happens. The given symbols are used to create a new class (either anonymously or named) and set the members provided ([see here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/62e66aedb08745eb7ff95575b5555c72baf1d961/struct.c#L464))

Last let's look at # 3:

```
# 3
u = UserPreview.new(1, 'hans@peter.de', 'Hans Peter')
```

In this case the [C function `rb_struct_initialize_m`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/62e66aedb08745eb7ff95575b5555c72baf1d961/struct.c#L657) is called. Since you provided just a list of arguments the code just walks the member fields and set each one in turn:

```
for (long i=0; i<argc; i++) {
  RSTRUCT_SET(self, i, argv[i]);
```